# API Gateway Response Download File using Node, PDFMake, Serverless

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, pdfmake, serverless-framework

I am in the process of migrating my NodeJS project to API Gateway and I cannot figure out how to download a file from Lambda.

Here is a snippet of the response code on my local Node project.

```
app.get('/downloadPDF', function (req, res) {
  res.setHeader('Content-disposition', 'attachment; filename=test.pdf');
  res.setHeader('Content-type', 'application/pdf');
  var PdfPrinter = require('pdfmake');
  var printer = new PdfPrinter(fonts);

  var pdfDoc = printer.createPdfKitDocument(dd);
  pdfDoc.pipe(res);
  pdfDoc.end();
});
```

Piping to the response I was able to get back a PDF.

Here is a snippet of my lambda function using serverless.

```
module.exports.createPDF = (event, context) => {
  var PdfPrinter = require('pdfmake');
  var printer = new PdfPrinter(fonts);

  var pdfDoc = printer.createPdfKitDocument(dd);
  pdfDoc.pipe(res);
  pdfDoc.end();
}
```

Here is the endpoint in my serverless.yml

```
createPDF:
handler: functions.myFunction
events:
  - http:
      path: services/getPDF
      method: get
      response:
        headers:
          Content-Type: "'application/pdf'"
          Content-disposition: "'attachment; filename=test.pdf'"
```

I don't know how to get reference to the response object in Lambda to pipe to. Is that possible? Is there another way?

---

**Update**

I ended up solving this issue by returning the base64 encoded PDF binary in a JSON response and decoding on the client.
Note: using the base64 decoding in the response mapping template did not work.

Sample code:

```
    var buffers = [];
pdfDoc.on('data', buffers.push.bind(buffers));

pdfDoc.on('end', function () {
    var bufCat = Buffer.concat(buffers);

    var pdfBase64 = bufCat.toString('base64');

return cb(null, 
    {"statusCode": 200,
    "headers": {"Content-Type": "application/json"},
    "body": pdfBase64});
});
```

Answer (score 2):

`API Gateway` doesn't support sending binary responses. As an alternative, you can have your `Lambda` store binary data in `S3` and return `HTTP` redirect to the `S3` object location via the `Location` header.

Comment: Great suggestion and I believe this would work, however storage does not fit into the requirements at this time. I hope this helps others!

Answer (score 1):

API Gateway does not natively support binary data. Some of our customers have had success base64 encoding the data in Lambda, including in a JSON reponse and using response mapping template to decode the data to respond to the client.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! Unfortunately I did not have success going this route but it give me some experience with response mapping templates.